# Pandas "to_csv" method magnifying file size

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, export-to-csv

I am using a csv file as a database to store values and I am pulling the data from an external source using python. When using the "to_csv" method to append the new data that came in, it seems to grow the file size exponentially, even though a few rows (10) are appended. Anyone know why this is the case? The csv file currently contains around 500k rows.

Is there a way to fix this or use another method to append data without growing the csv file size in an exponential way?

Comment: There is not enough information here to even verify what you are saying is true. Indeed, I am practically certain it isn't true. Unless each row you add has exponentially more information (possible for csv, although highly unusual). In any case, `.to_csv` is writing a csv *of what you tell it to in a normal way*. So this all comes down to *what you are doing*. And fundamentally, we aren't going to be able to help you without having **any details**

Comment: But if you want a database... *why don't you use an actual database*? Python comes with sqlite